# запуск хрома на одном ядре; профилирование веб приложений

Tags: javascript, linux, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

### 1. хром на одном ядре

a) имеет ли смысл в контексте профилирования ? - для более точных измерений

например у меня проц(2630qm) - 4 ядра 8 потоков + буст для полного счастья

б) как это сделать в линукс'е ?

- пока писал, придумал - виртуалка, но это не (спортивно)удобно
- пробовал так:

  - `taskset 0x00000001 google-chrome --single-process`
  - `taskset 0x00000001 google-chrome`
  - `taskset -c 1 google-chrome --single-process`
  - `taskset -c 1 google-chrome`

проверял с помощью сайта
http://pmav.eu/stuff/javascript-webworkers установив количество воркеров = 16 и наблюдая за загрузкой процессора

**UPD**: закрытие хрома всё же дало желаемый результат

```
killall google-chrome
killall google
taskset 0x00000001 google-chrome
```

в) если есть какие мысли про буст - тоже прошу озвучить.

### 2.  где почитать про такие инструменты как профилирование и аудит в хроме ? (ру./англ.)

Comment: Если вам будет полезно, в Chrome Dev Tools есть свой инструмент для замедления CPU: во вкладке Performance -> нажать шестеренку справа -> CPU throttling.